# PHP performance issue

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get the coin data of this website: http://www.tf2wh.com.

With this script:

```
$name = $_POST["item"];

$url = file_get_contents("http://www.tf2wh.com/allitems");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$dom->saveHTML();

$code = "";
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::class, "entry qual")]') as $e ) {
    $code .= $e->nodeValue;
}
$code = substr($code,strpos($code,$name)-30,30);
$code = explode("(",$code);
$coins = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($code[0]); $i++){
    if(is_numeric($code[0][$i])){
        $coins .= $code[0][$i];
    }
}
echo $coins;
```

It works fine but there are two problems. First, its sooo slow, the time between request and response is around 15-30 seconds. Second, sometime this error occurs:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\steammarket\getCoins.php on line 6

How can I fix this problem with the performance issue.

Comment: Have you checked whether they have an API, so you don't have to scrape the web page?

Comment: Did you check what line is slow? Use some profiling tool? Or print a timestamp?

Comment: @Barmar No there isn't an API to get the coin data.

Comment: @LajosVeres I don't know :), i am new in php and have no idea how i should handle this problem.

Comment: Avg time to load that site is already 2 - 3 secs

Comment: For your situation, how often do you need to get this data? If you are presently getting it in a web request, consider getting it in an offline process, and store the data in a database. An daily/hourly cron would be ideal.

Comment: @DarkBee thanks but Buse Gönen solve it :)

Comment: If so then the question u posted is not the right question imho

Comment: @halfer in realy time or with a short delay like 500ms. This webpage calculated an item wh price and compare it with the normal wh price and then with the steam market price. So you can see weather you can make profit or not by selling this item.

Comment: @DarkBee it is the right question because the ajax request overlaps each other and the php timed out/threw an error. But with set_time_limit(0) they dont timeout anymore.

Comment: Yes but that does not improve/solve any of the `performance` issue u have. Anyway no worries ^^ Glad u can work around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect site slow. 
First php code  **set_time_limit(0);**  or **ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);** //300 seconds = 5 minutes

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$name = $_POST["item"];

$url = file_get_contents("http://www.tf2wh.com/allitems");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$dom->saveHTML();

$code = "";
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::class, "entry qual")]') as $e ) {
    $code .= $e->nodeValue;
}
$code = substr($code,strpos($code,$name)-30,30);
$code = explode("(",$code);
$coins = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($code[0]); $i++){
    if(is_numeric($code[0][$i])){
        $coins .= $code[0][$i];
    }
}
echo $coins;
```